# Negating complex (developer input) RegExp

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regexp-replace

I have a function that needs to trim string but using regular expression looks like this:

```
function trim(value: string, allowedRuleset: RegExp): string {
    // some logic here
}
```

Supposed the dev tries to do this

```
trim('Ne 145', /[^ ]/g) // Should return `Ne145`
trim('Ne 145', /^[^ ]{1,4}$/g) // Should return 'Ne14'
```

Does anyone know how to invert the `allowedRuleset` RegExp?

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: But `/^[^ ]$/` doesn't match `Ne145`. Is the idea to transform the string so it matches the given regex?

Comment: your regex  matches only 1 non-space character.

Comment: @onyambu I'm using Typescript
I've edited the samples to make it clear

Comment: @August the idea is to trim the string so only all characters matched by `allowedRuleset` RegExp were left on the string

Comment: @user12280241 this seems ill-defined. Couldn’t the 2nd example return N, or Ne, or Ne4, etc.? Sounds like you want to generate matches for the given regex, constrained to be substrings of `value`, of which the closest (by some metric) to the original string is chosen. I think this could end up being quite complex.